# Collect all Javascript, CSS and images for deployment of a website or app?

Tags: html, css, deployment, build, cordova

I have a Phonegap project that contains a lot of html-files, javascript files, css-files and images.

When I build the app I want to keep it as small as possible, so I want to exclude all files that are NOT used in the html-files. For example some images in the 'img' directory might not be used in the app.

Somehow I need to make a build-script that searches in every html and css file for other files that are included. Of course the problem is that in each file url's can be relative or absolute.

Is this something that can be automated (maybe with ant?) , or does everybody always pick all necessary files by hand for deployment?

Comment: ok, what are you using as ide?

Comment: there are usually scripts for finding "usages of files" in ides, like IntelliJ

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA 12

Comment: you can right click on a folder or file and then select find usages, and intellij will find file references in the other files.

Comment: Actually I need some kind of thing that finds all references and copies all the right files to the right places...

Comment: I feel like that's a bit risky thing to do as your app will have a different root than your css files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**grunt.js**](http://gruntjs.com/)

> In one word: automation. The less work you have to do when performing
>   repetitive tasks like minification, compilation, unit testing,
>   linting, etc, the easier your job becomes.

Basically you can minify and merge all your css in one file as well as all js in one file. At the same time you can exclude files for build process. You can google for example code. I. E.

https://coderwall.com/p/e0jxea or https://github.com/centralway/grunt-phonegap-build (phonegap project grunt based)